# Задать каждому первому символу в строчке массива верхний регистр js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не доходит, как каждому слову добавить верхний регистр в первой букве... Если возможно, то нужно выполнить через условие(заглавная ли буква).

```js
do {
  var arr = prompt("Enter", "Hi|my|name|is|Kreami|");
} while (arr == null);

var arrSplt = arr.split("|");

for (var i = 0; i < arrSplt.length; i++) {

  arrSplt[i][0].toUpperCase();
  document.write("Ячейка массива # " + (i + 1) + " = " + arrSplt[i] + '<br>');

  if (arrSplt[arrSplt.length - 1] == "") {
    arrSplt.pop();
  }

}

console.log("Длина массива равна: " + arrSplt.length);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
do {
  var arr = prompt("Enter", "Hi|my|name|is|Kreami|");
} while (arr == null);

var arrSplt = arr.split("|");

for (var i = 0; i < arrSplt.length; i++) {

  //arrSplt[i][0].toUpperCase(); //не используется
  //document.write("Ячейка массива # " + (i + 1) + " = " + arrSplt[i] + '<br>');
  document.write("Ячейка массива # " + (i + 1) + " = " + arrSplt[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arrSplt[i].substr(1) + '<br>');
  if (arrSplt[arrSplt.length - 1] == "") {
    arrSplt.pop();
  }

}

console.log("Длина массива равна: " + arrSplt.length);
```

**UPD:** [вместо *index* лучше использовать *charAt()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943760/5398808). В Вашем случае, если будете использовать *index* (`arrSplt[i][0]`) при переводе первого символа в верхний регистр, то в случае пустого элемента массива будет ошибка и после ошибки код не выполнится, а если использовать *charAt()* (`arrSplt[i].charAt(0)`), то ошибки не будет и код выполнится целиком.

Comment: Благодарю вас, исправлю